# Using a HFS+ formatted Time Machine backup in APFS Catalina

Tags: backup, time-machine, apfs, hfs+

I've updated to MacOS Catalina on my MacBook Air. The system drive has been formatted as APFS now. I want to revert back to an older state of the system with an older MacOS (I believe it's Yosemite) and I have it as a Time Machine backup on an external drive, but in a HSF+ format. If I reboot the computer in recover mode (command+R) and chose "restore from Time Machine backup" the system won't let me use the backup on the external drive. The reason given is that it's not possible to recover from a HFS+ backup on an APFS system drive.

Is there any way around this? Can I reformat the internal drive as HFS+ and then use my Time Machine backup?